# move discussion to chat no longer available

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

I notice the from last two days chat option in not available while you comment on the post. someone else experience the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option exists.

It only shows up if there is an extended back and forth between two people in a comment thread - it isn't there all the time.